# How i can fetch array form of data from MYSQL database and show it in android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, fetch

i am trying to fetch arrays form of data which i store in form of JSON in mysql database.How i can show it in my android project.I am recieving following data from mysql data base

**"[rice, rice, kabab]""[rice, rice, kabab, kabab, kabab]"**

I am using Volley library in my android project
I Have store multiple arrays in mysql database Now i want to fetch these multiple arrays ??

Answer (score 0):

Convert the received data in to JSON

`JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);`

then you can simply traverse through that array and make it visualized

this link might help :
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-mysql-database-android/

Comment: Thank you But by this method i am recieving only first array which i stored

Comment: Then try remove the `]" "[` from the incoming string, it is very easy if you know string manipulation just convert `"[rice, rice, kabab]""[rice, rice, kabab, kabab, kabab]"` to `"[rice, rice, kabab, rice, rice, kabab, kabab, kabab]"` and then try to convert it to json.. and second thing is that you are not doing this process in correct way. My SQL output should never look like this, I don't know how you are storing and retrieving the data from mysql data. Store these things in a proper way in the database then the results would be good i guess.